# Iphone database support

Tags: iphone, database

Guys which Database is Support apple iphone application and is Database similar to Oracle and Sql etc..,
Let me know About Apple iphone database .
please give me any example appliccation to know the process ..

how to connect Application to DataBase 
for instance i have a USername , Password  and there is a Submit Button , when i hit the submit Button it will store the values in the Database.( we dont requiired any validations and any retutn page) whether it is going to store the values in the DB Good or not

Thanks& Regards
Jagadeesh

Comment: Your question is completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

There is support for SQLlite and then there is Apples own ORM layer called Core Data.
SQLlite is traditional database access using text commands to "select", "create", "insert" etc.

Core Data will let you save and retrieve entire objects, they also handle memory management for you.

If you only need to save a username and a password maybe a plist file would suffice?
I use Core Data for larger data sets and data with different relations.

The reason all these technologies are included is probably that the each have their advantages and problems:)

Comment: Thanks RickiG 
i  mention in my previous post like username and password for References,
what exactly im asking is DataBase Support for IPhone Apps